# What does the src_rect parameter in CanvasItem.draw_texture_rect_region() do?

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

Now, the official documentation sadly only reads:

> void draw_texture_rect_region ( Texture2D texture, Rect2 rect, Rect2 src_rect, Color modulate=Color(1, 1, 1, 1), bool transpose=false, bool clip_uv=true )

> Draws a textured rectangle region at a given position, optionally modulated by a color. If transpose is true, the texture will have its X and Y coordinates swapped.

I would like to ask what the parameter Rect2 src_rect does.

I am trying to draw a repeating texture into a CanvasItem (a button) and am trying to use the CanvasItem.draw_texture_rect_region() method to do so.
Specifically, my function looks like this:

```
# size_in_cells is the amount of grid cells the object is supposed to use.

# cell_size is the side length of the (square) cell

# blockTexture is the CompressedTexture2D I am using as a texture. As it has a native resolution of 
# 64 by 64 pixels I need to scale it to match the cell_size.

func _draw():
    for i in range(size_in_cells):
        draw_texture_rect_region(blockTexture, \
        Rect2(Vector2((self.get_rect().size.x/size_in_cells)*i,0), Vector2(cell_size, cell_size)),\
        self.get_rect())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`src_rect` is the region of the given **texture** to draw onto the canvas item's `rect`.

This can be read as "draw pixels from texture source rectangle onto canvas item's destination rectangle."

Examples:

1. You want to draw the whole texture onto the canvas at position (10, 10) with size (100, 100).

```
var dst_rect = Rect2(10, 10, 100, 100)
var src_rect = Rect2(Vector2(), texture.get_size())
draw_texture_rect_region(texture, dst_rect, src_rect)
```

2. The texture is an atlas with a row of 3 images. Each image is 32x32 pixels. You want to draw the second image on the canvas at position (64, 64) with size (32, 32).

```
var image_index = 1
var dst_rect = Rect2(64, 64, 32, 32)
var src_rect = Rect2(32 * image_index, 0, 32, 32)
draw_texture_rect_region(texture, dst_rect, src_rect)
```

Hope this helps.